# If $f'$ changes sign on both sides of a specific point $x_0$, then $f$ has an extremum at that point $x_0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Obviously, if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ the statement is right. But do we know if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, so we can say if the statement is right or wrong?

Comment: What exactly does it mean 'changes sign'? Do you know that on each side there is a constant sign at all nearby points and those signs are different? Or all you know is that there are two points, one on each side, and the derivative on them have different signs?

Comment: For example, f ' > 0 at left of x0 and f ' < 0 at right of x0.

Comment: Yes, use [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). Assume those signs you said. If there is a point $x<x_0$ for which $f(x)>f(x_0)$ then, by the Mean Value Theorem there is a point $z$ in $(x,x_0)$ such that $f'(z)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}<0$. Contradiction. Therefore, $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for all $x<x_0$. Do the corresponding work on the other side to get that $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for all $x>x_0$.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding right here. My question is if we know that f is continuous at x0 just by that statement i have written above. Specifically, if since there's the f ' , that means that f is differentiable.

Comment: Existence of the derivative implies continuity. Moreover, you don't need to know that the derivative exists at $x_0$, but you do need to know that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Any misunderstanding is due to you not asking what you want to ask.

Comment: I know all the things you said, i have a very simple question. This specific statement implies that f is differentiable (so it is continuous) in x0 or not?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work in general. For example,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x + 1 & \text{if } x < 1 \\ 2 - x & \text{if } x \ge 1 \end{cases}.$$
Such a function has a supremum of $2$, but no actual maximum.

Comment: My question is that, since there's the f ' , that means that f is differentiable? So f is continuous? Or we cannot say that?

Comment: If the derivative exists at the actual point, then $f$ is continuous at that point. I was assuming that, because you were talking about discontinuity, $f$ only had to be differentiable (and hence continuous) around a point, not at the point.